# cant upload media/pictures to my wordpress site, cant upload anything to my database

Tags: images, uploads, media

> “test-pic.jpg” has failed to upload.
> Could not insert attachment into the database.

this is the message keeps popping up when I upload any media to my WP site .
please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Is that the exact error message you're getting? I can't find that in the core WordPress code.

Comment: Does the WordPress user you've configured in wp-config have permission to write to the database? Are there are any errors in your site's error log (the server log, or PHP error log if separate, or wp-content/debug.log if you've enabled that) with more information? There should be a more detailed error message somewhere that hopefully you can show us.